# Elasticsearch groovy script to iterate through nested object for scoring throws error

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a nested object `mygroup` in my document as follows:

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "mygroup": [
    {
      "start": 200,
      "end": 490
    },
    {
      "start": 800,
      "end": 900
    },
    {
      "start": 22,
      "end": 49
    }
  ]
}
```

One of my `script_score` in my `function_score` is as follows:

```
"script_score": {
  "params": {
    "gboost": -1350,
    "desired": 30,
    "delta": 10
  },
  "script": "_source['mygroup'].values.any{ if(it -> it.end >= desired &&  it.start <= desired) { return (it.end - delta) * 2} };" 
}
```

Here my goal is to find an object that matches my condition where `start` is >= desired AND `end` <= desired (There is always ONLY one object that will suffice this condition, that's guaranteed in my data storage), once I find that object then I would like to return `(it.end - delta) * 2` for score calculation

My above script `"_source['mygroup'].values.any{ if(it -> it.end >= desired &&  it.start <= desired) { return (it.end - delta) * 2} };"` is not working and it keeps throwing error. I am using ES 2.3 and groovy for scripting language.

If I use `doc['mygroup']` at the place of `_source['mygroup']`, that also doesn't help

Comment: Did you solve this? Facing the same issue in filter script